# Setting up an app.route for a redirect that provides a request token

Tags: flask, flask-login

I am trying to connect to a system that has the following authentication:
1. Flask will have to redirect to a url that will take a 2 factor authentication
2. A successful authentication will result in the system sending back a post to a redirect URL with the request token in the url
3. We should then use this request token to get an access token, which then gives us access to the system.

The problem i am facing is that the url keeps changing (for step2) and I do not know how to set up an app.route that would catch all.

Is there any way to do that in flask?

Answer (score 0):

This question has been resolved.

You can just use request.args and obtain the required fields.

Regards,
S